# PHP HTML: Checkbox value is not the expected

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a checkbox which value is getting from db -> `$row['nama']`

```
<label><input type='checkbox' value=".$row['nama'].">".$row['nama']."</label>
```

Why the HTML output become:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Yulia" nur="" jannah,="" sst="">Yulia Nur Jannah, SST</label>
```

How to make this html output like below?

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Yulia Nur Jannah, SST">Yulia Nur Jannah, SST</label>
```

TIA :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<label><input type='checkbox' value='".$row['nama']."'>'".$row['nama']."'</label>
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<label><input type='checkbox' value="<?php echo $row['nama'] ?>"><?php echo $row['nama'] ?></label>
```

or

```
echo "<label><input type='checkbox' value='".$row['nama']."'>".$row['nama']."</label>";
```